# How can I get *ngFor to show only specific data for the clicked element in different components? Angular4

Tags: angular, components, ngfor

I'm trying to learn Angular by doing some projects. One of them is [Reader](https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/4/reader/index.html#/books).

I have 3 components: Bookshelf, Book and Chapter.
When I retrieve data from a json file, in BookComponent, the *ngFor displays all the books, but I need to display only the data for selected/clicked book. 
My code looks like this:

bookshelf.component.html

```
<div class="bookshelf row" >
  <div class="book col-md-3" *ngFor="let book of books; let i=index">
    <a [routerLink]="['/book/:id']">
      <img src="{{ book.cover }}"/>
      <h3 class="title">{{ book.title }}</h3>
      <p class="author">{{ book.author }}</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

bookshelf.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core'; 
import { DataService } from '../data.service'; 
import { Http } from '@angular/http'; 

@Component({   
  selector: 'app-bookshelf',   
  templateUrl: './bookshelf.component.html',   
  styleUrls: ['./bookshelf.component.css'] 
}) 

export class BookshelfComponent implements OnInit {   
  books = [];   

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {   } 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.fetchData().subscribe(
      (data) => this.books = data
    )
  }
}
```

book.component.html

```
<a class="button back" [routerLink]="['']">Back</a>
<div class="book-detail" *ngFor="let book of books; let i=index">
  <img src="{{ book.cover }}" />
  <h3 class="title">{{ book.title }}</h3>
  <p class="author">{{ book.author }}</p>
  <p class="description">{{ book.description }}</p>
  <a class="button" [routerLink]="['/chapter']">Read</a>
</div>
```

book.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-book',
  templateUrl: './book.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book.component.css']
})
export class BookComponent implements OnInit {
  books = [];

constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.fetchData().subscribe(
    (data) => this.books = data
    )
  }
}
```

books.json

```
[
  {
    "title": "Metamorphosis",
    "cover": "../assets/metamorphosis.jpg",
    "author": "Franz Kafka",
    "description": "The story...",
    "chapters": [
      {
        "title": "I",
        "paragraphs": ["One morning... "]
      },
      {
        "title": "II",
        "paragraphs": ["No one... "]
      },
{
    "title": "Strange Case of Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde",
    "cover": "../assets/drjekyllmrhyde.jpg",
    "author": "Robert Louis Stevenson",
    "description": "London lawyer...",
    "chapters": [
      {
        "title": "Story of the Door",
        "paragraphs": ["Mr. Utterson... "]
      },
      {
        "title": "Search for Mr. Hyde",
        "paragraphs": ["That evening ... "]
      },
{
    "title": "Heart of Darkness",
    "cover": "../assets/heartofdarkness.jpg",
    "author": "Joseph Conrad",
    "description": "The story...",
    "chapters": [
      {
        "title": "I",
        "paragraphs": ["The Nellie... "]
      },
      {
        "title": "II",
        "paragraphs": ["\"One evening... "]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I was able to do this with "$routeParams" in the old AngularJs, now I think it's deprecated.
Does anybody know how can I get only the specific book data displayed?

Comment: I made a detailed answer here that might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43691769/how-to-properly-have-to-make-an-ajax-call-prior-to-accessing-scope-variable-load/43747562#43747562

Comment: Have you take a look at `*ngIf` ?

Comment: Thank you so much, Maxime! This is very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maxime gave you a good link to follow, I'd just thought I'd present the version utilizing the JSON file.

Your code looks pretty good as is. The only thing you seem to miss is the routing part and getting that one book.

So your JSON currently has no `id` for each book, but I added one to the code.
So when you display your books your routerlink should look like this:

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/book/'+book.id]">
```

where we add the book id as parameter. When navigating, we then get the route param and make the http-call to get that specific book, so inject `ActivatedRoute` to your book-component constructor and then the `OnInit` should look like this:

```ts
 ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        let id = params['id']; // get parameter
        this.dataService.getBook(id) 
          .subscribe(data => {
            this.book = data;
          })
    )}
  }
```

Then the corresponding Service function `getBook` looks like the following, where we fetch all books and then find the correct book based on the id:

```ts
getBook(id) {
  return this.http.get('url')
    .map(res => res.json().find(x => x.id == id))
}
```

That should be it :) Also check this

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/spFg6VOlOvLmwBI0NKd7?p=preview)

Comment: Now I got it! Finally! This is very helpful! 
A million thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear! You are very welcome. Have a good day and happy coding! :)